# ¿Como arreglar el print para que imprima dos variables a la vez?

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo en la programación de Python y necesito ayuda con mi código, logro abrir un archivo .txt, lo que no entiendo como hacer para que mi datos aparezcan en dos columnas, una ayuda con el print.
Este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd  

data = pd.read_csv('Datos.txt',header = 1, delim_whitespace = True)

x = data.ix[:,1]
y = data.ix[:,2]

print(x)
print(y)
```

Muchas gracias.
los datos son:

Comment: Try wrapping them using a dataframe `pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y))`

Comment: ¿estas extrayendo de forma separada dos columnas y luego quieres volver a "juntarlas"? ¿es eso? si es así, ¿por que no simplemente extraes las dos columnas con `data.ix[:,1:3]`?. Por cierto el método `ix()` esta deprecado:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html

Comment: Acabo de ver que comenté en Inglés sin querer xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Puede imprimir directamente seleccionando las filas y columnas, para ello tenga en cuenta que el metodo `ix` ya esta obsoleto y no es recomendable usarlo.

En cambio, puede usar el metodo `iloc` que permite seleccionar los rangos de filas y columnas a mostrar

Para mostrar como usted indica las columnas 1 y 2 del dataframe, solo basta correr:

```
print(data.iloc[:, 1:3])
```

El primer rango es para las filas y el segundo es para el numero de columnas - 1.

2. Tambien puede asignar este valor a una variable si va a operar estos valores mas adelante y pues tambien puede imprimirla

```
X_data = data.iloc[:, 1:3]
print(X_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

para que tus datos aparezcan en dos columnas , puedes usar el metodo `.format()` y mencionar los espacios que quieres dejar entre dichas columnas , esta pregunta ya fue contestada te dejo el [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236759/python-print-in-two-columns) para que tengas idea de como aplicarlo a tu codigo :) , suerte